# The zen way of convert params[:date] to Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the most elegant way of converting a `params[:date]` field to a `Date` object?

```
"date"=>{"day"=>"13", "year"=>"2012", "month"=>"4"}
```

Currently, I have the following code in the `controller`:

```
@date = Date.current
if params[:date]
  yy = mm = dd = 0
  yy = params[:date][:year].to_i  if params[:date][:year]
  mm = params[:date][:month].to_i if params[:date][:month]
  dd = params[:date][:day].to_i   if params[:date][:day]
  @date = Date::civil(yy, mm, dd) if Date::valid_date?(yy, mm, dd)
end
```

and inside the `view`'s `form_tag`:

```
<%= select_date(@date, :order => [:year, :month, :day], :prefix => 'date') %>
```

Comment: I would prefer to send a string and delegate parsing with a shorter line, I suppose it can be possible, but don't know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will return the valid date or time object . Try :

```
@date = Date.parse("#{params[:date]['day']}-#{params[:date]['month']}-#{params[:date]['year']}") if params[:date]
OR
@date = Time.parse("#{params[:date]['day']}-#{params[:date]['month']}-#{params[:date]['year']}") if params[:date]

@date ||= Date.current
```