# Format date "dd/mm/YYYY" to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Inside my controller, Im getting a params[:date] in portuguese format, like this: **"dd/mm/YYYY"**. 
How do I change it back to mysql format? Im used to php, and there, i would create a function that uses **explode**, and then, I would have to concatenate the numbers with '-'.

Does rails have any function to convert this date better?

Comment: Check this out. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136279/the-zen-way-of-convert-paramsdate-to-date)

Comment: The Rails `Date.parse` method can handle this.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, that solved my problem.